# gnuplot xrange not being accepted properly?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a large (80MB+) input file with samples like this (timestamp in first column is UNIX-epoch with milliseconds):

```
1433908383.289  25219.334734712 25219.946173616 9.512001270e-06 1.003999932e-05 9.512001270e-06 1.003999932e-05 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00
1433908383.336  25219.364742792 25219.985225320 9.528001101e-06 1.003999932e-05 9.528001101e-06 1.003999932e-05 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00
1433908383.362  25219.399744192 25220.016488160 9.512001270e-06 1.003199941e-05 9.512001270e-06 1.003199941e-05 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00
1433908383.386  25219.429734824 25220.039910600 9.504001355e-06 1.003999932e-05 9.504001355e-06 1.003999932e-05 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00
```

that, when plotted with the following script:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font "arial,10" size 1024, 768;
set key below;
set grid;

set xdata time;
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S";
set format x "%H:%M:%S";
set datafile separator "\t";
set xlabel "Time (UTC)";
set ylabel "seconds";

set datafile nofpe_trap;

plot "data.tsv" using ($1-946684800):6 with points linecolor rgbcolor "#EE0000" axes x1y1 title "plot 1";
```

produces the following graph:

[image]

But when I add the following to just before the `plot` command:

```
set xrange ["10:00:00","11:00:00"]
```

I instead get no output and the following error:

```
gnuplot> plot "data.tsv" using ($1-946684800):6 with points linecolor rgbcolor "#EE0000" axes x1y1 title "plot 1";
                                                                                                                ^
     line 0: all points y value undefined!
```

I have matched up the `timefmt` and there is clearly data in this range. So what gives?

*Notes: This is gnuplot 4.4 and the image below has the wrong axis labels because I originally left out a `8` in the epoch offset.*

Comment: The problem is, that "10:00:00" isn't uniquely defined. If no day, month and year is given, gnuplot 4.4 uses the first January 2000, which is not where your data is located.

Comment: But don't I have to give `xrange` in the `timefmt` format? My `timefmt` has no date component. How can I work around that?

Comment: Setting the xrange is the only application of your `set timefmt`, because you explicitely circumvent the timefmt settings when reading in the data. Instead of this you could also give the xrange in seconds (since jan 1st 2000), like you do for the x-values.

Comment: @Christoph: Ahhhh so is that what `$1` is doing, circumventing `timefmt`? Think I'm getting it.

Comment: Yes, I thought this was clear. Ups :) I edited the other answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works when I provide numeric timestamps as the range, despite the fact that my `timefmt` looks like a human-readable time string:

```
set xrange [1444122000:1433928600]
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this a fake date. Your data set contains complete date time information (Unix timestamp), so if you want to specify a range to plot, you must also give complete date times for the xrange limits. How should gnuplot know to which date you refer to? That you can specify the xrange in the same format as the input data makes sense if you use the `timefmt` for both parsing the input data and setting the xrange.

Comment: @Christoph: Well in the case of the different log files that only store "HH:MM:SS", the date _is_ entirely artificial. This part of the answer/solution is a bit tangential though as the question was about the file with UNIX timestamps.

Comment: Yes, and in the case your log file uses only "HH:MM:SS" you also don't need this artificial date. That's the whole point.